# Windows 7 - use [Win key] + Space for Switch Language

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, language, ime

In windows 8, I love how I can switch to Japanese input by pressing [Win key] + [space bar].

Can I do this in Windows 7 without auto hotkey or special programs?

Comment: You mean instead of the default Alt + Shift?

Answer (score 3):

1. your default switch language shortcut should be 'Shift'+'Ctrl'
2. download Autohotkey (http://autohotkey.com)
3. install and run it
4. right click by icon in tray menu -> 'Edit This Script'
5. remove or comment (each comment line started with ';') existed script
6. copy-paste this:

`#Space::
 WinWait, Program Manager, 
 Send, {CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}`

7. save changes and close editor
8. if autohotkey program not running after restart, you should manually added it to autorun

Comment: Cannot even launch Autohotkey. `script not found` just after installation lol

Comment: But the question was specifically WITHOUT "autohotkey"...

Answer (score 0):

Go to start -> Type Language -> Change Keyboard or other Input Languages ->
Go to the Keyboards and Languages Tab, and choose change keyboards. -> Change Key sequence...

But, it appears that key sequence is not supported / present.

[image]

Comment: This is the reason of the question itself, Capitan Obvious.